# different types of array declaration in java

Tags: java

What kind of deference / meaning between the underline declaration of array in java.

```
int[] touchMe;
```

OR

```
int touchMe[];
```

OR

```
int[] touchMe[];
```

Comment: All are ok. Syntactic sugar.

Comment: i want to know advance ... suppose if i pass an array in function ...